# Why does the mouseover method don't work on node's text in a dialog?

Tags: jquery, d3.js, modal-dialog, mouseover

I am using d3.js to draw reingold-tilford Tree.I add a mouseover function to the node like this:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
  return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").text(function() {
    d.name;
  })
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
      return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
    });
```

It works fine in one html,However,When I load this html into a modal dialog,the mouseover function does not take effect over the text of the node,I can only see the tooltip when hovering on the circle.

Please give me a hand!

Comment: looks like you are dealing with dynamic elements.... use event delegation instead

Comment: can you share the selector part also

Comment: jQuery has no `style()` method, you should be using `css()`

Comment: @ArunPJohny P Johny Since I am new to jquery and How to do that?

Comment: @adeneo But it works fine in one page,I think the problem is the modal dialog I used.

Comment: Just open your console and check for errors.

Comment: @adeneo But there is no error when hovering over the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.
It turns out my original text has a css like:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

I removed it and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The element that you are trying to add the event to, does not exist at the moment when you are binding the event. To solve this problem you have to add the event to the document to get the event through propagation.

To solve your probelm you should change this:

```
$("mySelector").on("mouseover", function(e) { ... });
```

To this:

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "mySelector", function(e) { ... });
```

Comment: browser shows this: `<g class="node" transform="rotate(-36)translate(300)">
<circle r="6.5" style="stroke: steelblue; fill: steelblue;">
<text dy=".31em" text-anchor="start" transform="translate(8)">61.0.0.0/8</text>
</g>` I have tried your way but it did not work,what is wrong in my situation?